# The dreaded "parameter was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression" exception

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0, expression

I am trying to get an understanding of expressions. I am hitting the dreaded "parameter was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression" exception. I have seen Skeet answer this before as well as others online. However I just cannot "see" the problem. I am using Colin Meek's example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx and Matt Warren's VisitorExpression class http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/07/31/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-ii.aspx. I'm using a console app in VS 2010, framework 4.0. Sorry if this is beating a dead horse since it has been asked about before. Thanks for any help.

To be thorough, all the code is below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Expression<Func<Car, bool>> theCarIsRed = c => c.Color == "Red";
        Expression<Func<Car, bool>> theCarIsCheap = c => c.Price < 10.0;
        Expression<Func<Car, bool>> theCarIsRedOrCheap = theCarIsRed.Or(theCarIsCheap);

        Car one = new Car() { CarId = 1, Color = "Red", Price = 10.0 };
        Car two = new Car() { CarId = 2, Color = "Blue", Price = 9.0 };
        Car three = new Car() { CarId = 3, Color = "Black", Price = 5.0 };
        Car four = new Car() { CarId = 4, Color = "Red", Price = 5.0 };

        EntityDBContext context = new EntityDBContext();
        context.CarEntity.Add(one);
        context.CarEntity.Add(two);
        context.CarEntity.Add(three);
        context.CarEntity.Add(four);

        using (var db = context)
        {
            // Bang
            var query = db.CarEntity.AsQueryable().Where(theCarIsRedOrCheap).ToList();

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Color, item.Price);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Car 
{
    [Key]
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}


public static class Utility
{
    public static Expression<T> Compose<T>(this Expression<T> first,
        Expression<T> second, Func<Expression, Expression, Expression> merge)
    {
        var map = first.Parameters.Select((f, i) => new { f, s = second.Parameters[i] }).ToDictionary(p => p.s, p => p.f);

        var secondBody = ParameterRebinder.ReplaceParameters(map, second.Body);

        return Expression.Lambda<T>(merge(first.Body, second.Body), first.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> first, Expression<Func<T, bool>> second)
    {
        return first.Compose(second, Expression.And);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> first, Expression<Func<T, bool>> second)
    {
        return first.Compose(second, Expression.Or);
    }
}


public class ParameterRebinder : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> map;

    public ParameterRebinder(Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> map)
    {
        this.map = map ?? new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression>();
    }

    public static Expression ReplaceParameters(Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> map, Expression exp)
    {
        return new ParameterRebinder(map).Visit(exp);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression parmEx)
    {
        ParameterExpression replacement;
        if (map.TryGetValue(parmEx, out replacement))
        {
            parmEx = replacement;
        }

        return base.VisitParameter(parmEx);
    }
}

public abstract class ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected ExpressionVisitor()
    {
    }

    protected virtual Expression Visit(Expression exp)
    {
        if (exp == null)
        {
            return exp;
        }

        switch (exp.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.Negate:
            case ExpressionType.NegateChecked:
            case ExpressionType.Not:
            case ExpressionType.Convert:
            case ExpressionType.ConvertChecked:
            case ExpressionType.ArrayLength:
            case ExpressionType.Quote:
            case ExpressionType.TypeAs:
                return this.VisitUnary((UnaryExpression) exp);
            case ExpressionType.Add:
            case ExpressionType.AddChecked:
            case ExpressionType.Subtract:
            case ExpressionType.SubtractChecked:
            case ExpressionType.Multiply:
            case ExpressionType.MultiplyChecked:
            case ExpressionType.Divide:
            case ExpressionType.Modulo:
            case ExpressionType.And:
            case ExpressionType.AndAlso:
            case ExpressionType.Or:
            case ExpressionType.OrElse:
            case ExpressionType.LessThan:
            case ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual:
            case ExpressionType.GreaterThan:
            case ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual:
            case ExpressionType.Equal:
            case ExpressionType.NotEqual:
            case ExpressionType.Coalesce:
            case ExpressionType.ArrayIndex:
            case ExpressionType.RightShift:
            case ExpressionType.LeftShift:
            case ExpressionType.ExclusiveOr:
                return this.VisitBinary((BinaryExpression) exp);
            case ExpressionType.TypeIs:
                return this.VisitTypeIs((TypeBinaryExpression) exp);
            case ExpressionType.Conditional:
                return this.VisitConditional((ConditionalExpression) exp);
            case ExpressionType.Constant:
                return this.VisitConstant((ConstantExpression) exp);
            case ExpressionType.Parameter:
                return this.VisitParameter((ParameterExpression) exp);
            case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
                return this.VisitMemberAccess((MemberExpression) exp);
            case ExpressionType.Call:
                return this.VisitMethodCall((MethodCallExpression) exp);
            case ExpressionType.Lambda:
                return this.VisitLambda((LambdaExpression) exp);
            case ExpressionType.New:
                return this.VisitNew((NewExpression) exp);
            case ExpressionType.NewArrayInit:
            case ExpressionType.NewArrayBounds:
                return this.VisitNewArray((NewArrayExpression) exp);
            case ExpressionType.Invoke:
                return this.VisitInvocation((InvocationExpression) exp);
            case ExpressionType.MemberInit:
                return this.VisitMemberInit((MemberInitExpression) exp);
            case ExpressionType.ListInit:
                return this.VisitListInit((ListInitExpression) exp);
            default:
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Unhandled expression type: '{0}'", exp.NodeType));

        }
    }

    protected virtual MemberBinding VisitBinding(MemberBinding binding)
    {
        switch (binding.BindingType)
        {
            case MemberBindingType.Assignment:
                return this.VisitMemberAssignment((MemberAssignment) binding);
                case MemberBindingType.MemberBinding:
                return this.VisitMemberMemberBinding((MemberMemberBinding) binding);
                case MemberBindingType.ListBinding:
                return this.VisitMemberListBinding((MemberListBinding) binding);
            default:
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Unhandled binding type '{0}'", binding.BindingType));
        }
    }

    protected virtual Expression VisitListInit(ListInitExpression init)
    {
        NewExpression n = this.VisitNew(init.NewExpression);
        IEnumerable<ElementInit> initializers = this.VisitElementInitializerList(init.Initializers);

        if (n != init.NewExpression || initializers != init.Initializers)
        {
            return Expression.ListInit(n, initializers);
        }

        return init;
    }

    protected virtual Expression VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression memberInitExpression)
    {
        NewExpression n = this.VisitNew(memberInitExpression.NewExpression);
        IEnumerable<MemberBinding> bindings = this.VisitBindingList(memberInitExpression.Bindings);

        if (n != memberInitExpression.NewExpression || bindings != memberInitExpression.Bindings)
        {
            return Expression.MemberInit(n, bindings);
        }

        return memberInitExpression;
    }

    protected virtual Expression VisitInvocation(InvocationExpression invocationExpression)
    {
        IEnumerable<Expression> args = this.VisitExpressionList(invocationExpression.Arguments);
        Expression expr = this.Visit(invocationExpression.Expression);

        if (args != invocationExpression.Arguments || expr != invocationExpression.Expression)
        {
            return Expression.Invoke(expr, args);
        }

        return invocationExpression;
    }

    protected virtual Expression VisitNewArray(NewArrayExpression newArrayExpression)
    {
        IEnumerable<Expression> exprs = this.VisitExpressionList(newArrayExpression.Expressions);

        if (exprs != newArrayExpression.Expressions)
        {
            if (newArrayExpression.NodeType == ExpressionType.NewArrayInit)
            {
                return Expression.NewArrayInit(newArrayExpression.Type.GetElementType(), exprs);
            }
            else
            {
                return Expression.NewArrayBounds(newArrayExpression.Type.GetElementType());
            }
        }

        return newArrayExpression;
    }

    protected virtual NewExpression VisitNew(NewExpression newExpression)
    {
        IEnumerable<Expression> args = this.VisitExpressionList(newExpression.Arguments);

        if (args != newExpression.Arguments)
        {
            if (newExpression.Members != null)
            {
                return Expression.New(newExpression.Constructor, args, newExpression.Members);
            }
            else
            {
                return Expression.New(newExpression.Constructor, args);
            }
        }

        return newExpression;
    }

    protected virtual Expression VisitLambda(LambdaExpression lambdaExpression)
    {
        Expression body = this.Visit(lambdaExpression.Body);
        if (body != lambdaExpression.Body)
        {
            return Expression.Lambda(lambdaExpression.Type, body, lambdaExpression.Parameters);
        }

        return lambdaExpression;
    }

    protected virtual Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
    {
        Expression obj = this.Visit(methodCallExpression.Object);
        IEnumerable<Expression> args = this.VisitExpressionList(methodCallExpression.Arguments);

        if (obj != methodCallExpression.Object || args != methodCallExpression.Arguments)
        {
            return Expression.Call(obj, methodCallExpression.Method, args);
        }

        return methodCallExpression;
    }

    protected virtual Expression VisitMemberAccess(MemberExpression memberExpression)
    {
        Expression exp = this.Visit(memberExpression.Expression);

        if (exp != memberExpression.Expression)
        {
            return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(exp, memberExpression.Member);
        }

        return memberExpression;
    }

    protected virtual Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression parameterExpression)
    {
        return parameterExpression;
    }

    protected virtual Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression constantExpression)
    {
        return constantExpression;
    }

    protected virtual Expression VisitConditional(ConditionalExpression conditionalExpression)
    {
        Expression test = this.Visit(conditionalExpression.Test);
        Expression ifTrue = this.Visit(conditionalExpression.IfTrue);
        Expression ifFalse = this.Visit(conditionalExpression.IfFalse);

        if (test != conditionalExpression.Test || ifTrue != conditionalExpression.IfTrue || ifFalse != conditionalExpression.IfFalse)
        {
            return Expression.Condition(test, ifTrue, ifFalse);
        }

        return conditionalExpression;
    }

    protected virtual Expression VisitTypeIs(TypeBinaryExpression typeBinaryExpression)
    {
        Expression expr = this.Visit(typeBinaryExpression.Expression);
        if (expr != typeBinaryExpression)
        {
            return Expression.TypeIs(expr, typeBinaryExpression.TypeOperand);
        }

        return typeBinaryExpression;
    }

    protected virtual Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression binaryExpression)
    {
        Expression left = this.Visit(binaryExpression.Left);
        Expression right = this.Visit(binaryExpression.Right);
        Expression conversion = this.Visit(binaryExpression.Conversion);

        if (left != binaryExpression.Left || right != binaryExpression.Right || conversion != binaryExpression.Conversion)
        {
            if (binaryExpression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Coalesce && binaryExpression.Conversion != null)
            {
                return Expression.Coalesce(left, right, conversion as LambdaExpression);
            }
            else
            {
                return Expression.MakeBinary(binaryExpression.NodeType, left, right, binaryExpression.IsLiftedToNull,
                                             binaryExpression.Method);
            }
        }

        return binaryExpression;
    }

    protected virtual Expression VisitUnary(UnaryExpression unaryExpression)
    {
        Expression operand = this.Visit(unaryExpression.Operand);
        if (operand != unaryExpression.Operand)
        {
            return Expression.MakeUnary(unaryExpression.NodeType, operand, unaryExpression.Type,
                                        unaryExpression.Method);
        }

        return unaryExpression;
    }

    protected virtual ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> VisitExpressionList(ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> original)
    {
        List<Expression> list = null;

        for (int i = 0, n = original.Count; i < n; i++)
        {
            Expression p = this.Visit(original[i]);
            if (list != null)
            {
                list.Add(p);
            }
            else if (p != original[i])
            {
                list = new List<Expression>(n);
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                    list.Add(original[j]);
                }

                list.Add(p);
            }
        }

        return list != null ? list.AsReadOnly() : original;
    }

    protected virtual IEnumerable<MemberBinding> VisitBindingList(ReadOnlyCollection<MemberBinding> original)
    {
        List<MemberBinding> list = null;

        for (int i = 0, n = original.Count; i < n; i++)
        {
            MemberBinding b = this.VisitBinding(original[i]);

            if (list != null)
            {
                list.Add(b);
            }
            else if (b != original[i])
            {
                list = new List<MemberBinding>(n);

                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                    list.Add(original[j]);
                }

                list.Add(b);
            }
        }

        if (list != null)
        {
            return list;
        }

        return original;
    }

    protected virtual MemberAssignment VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment assignment)
    {
        Expression e = this.Visit(assignment.Expression);

        if (e != assignment.Expression)
        {
            return Expression.Bind(assignment.Member, e);
        }

        return assignment;
    }

    protected virtual MemberMemberBinding VisitMemberMemberBinding(MemberMemberBinding binding)
    {
        IEnumerable<MemberBinding> bindings = this.VisitBindingList(binding.Bindings);

        if (bindings != binding.Bindings)
        {
            return Expression.MemberBind(binding.Member, bindings);
        }

        return binding;
    }

    protected virtual MemberListBinding VisitMemberListBinding(MemberListBinding binding)
    {
        IEnumerable<ElementInit> initializers = this.VisitElementInitializerList(binding.Initializers);

        if (initializers != binding.Initializers)
        {
            return Expression.ListBind(binding.Member, initializers);
        }

        return binding;
    }

    protected virtual IEnumerable<ElementInit> VisitElementInitializerList(ReadOnlyCollection<ElementInit> original)
    {
        List<ElementInit> list = null;

        for (int i = 0, n = original.Count; i < n; i++)
        {
            ElementInit init = this.VisitElementInitializer(original[i]);

            if (list != null)
            {
                list.Add(init);
            }
            else if (init != original[i])
            {
                list = new List<ElementInit>(n);

                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                    list.Add(original[j]);
                }

                list.Add(init);
            }
        }

        if (list != null)
        {
            return list;
        }

        return original;
    }

    protected virtual ElementInit VisitElementInitializer(ElementInit initializer)
    {
        ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> arguments = this.VisitExpressionList(initializer.Arguments);

        if (arguments != initializer.Arguments)
        {
            return Expression.ElementInit(initializer.AddMethod, arguments);
        }

        return initializer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In utility try replacing the compose method with the following.

```
{
    var map = first.Parameters.Select((f, i) => new { f, s = second.Parameters[i] }).ToDictionary(p => p.s, p => p.f);

    var secondRebound = ParameterRebinder.ReplaceParameters(map, second);

    return Expression.Lambda<T>(merge(first.Body, secondRebound.Body), first.Parameters);
}
```