# Dividing an Expression in C# using Expression.AndAlso() causes an Exception

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

On my project written in C#, I've found a HUGE predicate that is used in this method of linq :

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate);
```

this predicate works perfectly, but it as so much condition that I struggled a lot before understanding it. I would like to make it readable. So I wrote several Expression.

But I have a runtime exception like this one : [The dreaded "parameter was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289836/the-dreaded-parameter-was-not-bound-in-the-specified-linq-to-entities-query-exp)

I wanted to try the answer but I still don't understand why the parameter (c) is a problem see :

```
// in a method
Func<string, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>> expr1 = (query) => return (c) => ... ;
Func<string, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>> expr2 = (query) => return  (c) => ... ;

var expr = Expression.AndAlso(expr1("a string").Body, expr2("same string").Body);

return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(expr , expr1("a string").Parameters[0]);
```

My question is to understand why this exception occures as finally I reverted to the huge predicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because where you see a single `c` parameter, in truth there are two different `c` parameters (let's call them `c1` and `c2`). So when you merge the two expressions you have:

```
c1 => c1.Something && c2.SomethingElse;
```

And the CLR gets angry because it can't find the `c2`.

Worse, as you wrote your code, you have **three** `c`!

```
c3 => c1.Something && c2.SomethingElse
```

This because you rebuild `expr1("a string")` twice (in the `Expression.AndAlso(expr1("a string").Body` and in the `expr1("a string").Parameters[0]`)!

You should have saved it!

```
var temp1 = expr1("a string");
var temp2 = expr2("same string");

var expr = Expression.AndAlso(temp1.Body, temp2.Body);

// now fix the expr so that it uses the parameters of temp1

return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(expr, temp1.Parameters);
```

To give a clear example:

```
var temp1a = expr1("a string");
var temp1b = expr1("a string");
var temp2 = expr2("same string");

Console.WriteLine(temp1a.Parameters[0] == temp1b.Parameters[0]); // False
Console.WriteLine(temp1a.Parameters[0] == temp2.Parameters[0]); // False
```

Now... My version of parameter replacer:

```
public class SimpleParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public readonly ReadOnlyCollection<ParameterExpression> From;
    public readonly ReadOnlyCollection<ParameterExpression> To;

    public SimpleParameterReplacer(ParameterExpression from, ParameterExpression to)
        : this(new[] { from }, new[] { to })
    {
    }

    public SimpleParameterReplacer(IList<ParameterExpression> from, IList<ParameterExpression> to)
    {
        if (from == null || from.Any(x => x == null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("from");
        }

        if (to == null || to.Any(x => x == null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("to");
        }

        if (from.Count != to.Count)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("to");
        }

        // Note that we should really clone from and to... But we will
        // ignore this!
        From = new ReadOnlyCollection<ParameterExpression>(from);
        To = new ReadOnlyCollection<ParameterExpression>(to);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        int ix = From.IndexOf(node);

        if (ix != -1)
        {
            node = To[ix];
        }

        return base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

You can use to change a single parameter or a parameter array... You can use it like:

```
var temp1 = expr1("a string");
var temp2 = expr2("same string");

var expr = Expression.AndAlso(temp1.Body, temp2.Body);
expr = new SimpleParameterReplacer(temp2.Parameters, temp1.Parameters).Visit(expr);

return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(expr, temp1.Parameters);
```

Comment: This is explaining the problem, but not helping him fix it.

Comment: @Servy *I wanted to try the answer but I still don't understand why the parameter (c) is a problem see :* and *My question is to understand why this exception occures as finally I reverted to the huge predicate.* He already has a response... But it doesn't comprehend what is the problem

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I stil have the same exception so I guess I still have two 'c' now !

Comment: @xanatos : indeed I wanted to understand the problem. I'll take the time later to pursue this issue.

Comment: @AMS I've added my version of parameter replacer and an example of how to use it.