# Casting derived class to parent class within expression

Tags: c#

I've got a base class (BankAccount) which then has a derived type of UkBankAccount.

I'm getting a list of fields for the child class as an expression:

```
var properties = new Expression<Func<UkBankAccount, object>>[] {
    x => x.Status,
    x => x.Name,
    x => x.SortCode,
    x => x.AccountNumber
};
```

But then want to cast it to type `BankAccount` so I can use it generically. I tried:

```
updatedProperties = properties.ToList()
   .Cast<Expression<Func<BankAccount, object>>>()
   .ToArray();
```

But that throws an invalid cast exception. Should I be able to cast within an Expression?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think that should work? You cannot assign a `List<UkBankAccount>` to a `List<BankAccount>` either.

Comment: If those fields are only on the subtype, what sense does it make to try and invoke those properties on a supertype object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `UkBankAccount` is a `BankAccount`

But a `Func<UkBankAccount, object>` is not assignable to a `Func<BankAccount, object>`, in fact it is the other way around: a `Func<BankAccount, object>` is  assignable to a `Func<UkBankAccount, object>`. Think about it: when you have a function that is capable of taking all kinds of accounts, surely it can take UK accounts. But the other way around is not true.

But that does not imply that a `Expression<Func<BankAccount, object>>` should be assignable to a `Expression<Func<UkBankAccount, object>>`. It is not. Generic contravariance does not work for classes.

And even then, what you seem to want is the other way around.

> Should I be able to cast within an Expression?

No, the type system does not allow a `Expression<Func<UkBankAccount, object>>` to be cast, converted or otherwise assigned to a `Expression<Func<BankAccount, object>>`.

What you need to do is something that produces the equivalent of

```
var properties = new Expression<Func<BankAccount, object>>[] {
    x => ((UkBankAccount)x).Status,
    x => ((UkBankAccount)x).Name,
    x => ((UkBankAccount)x).SortCode,
    x => ((UkBankAccount)x).AccountNumber
};
```

where the cast can be skipped if the property exists on BankAccount too.

Notice that those casts can fail, which is why a `Func<UkBankAccount, object>` is not assignable to a `Func<BankAccount, object>`.

Comment: So basically, you're saying, the OP is at a dead-end? Besides the canonical facts, which most of us are aware of, I'm not sure how this answer helps bring about the desired solution. And to be fair, maybe the OP *is* heading in the wrong direction. Just would like a clarifying statement on the OP's approach.

Comment: @code4life I have no doubt that you are aware of the canonical facts, but clearly OP is not.

Comment: @xanatos That is exactly what I said, no?

Comment: @KrisVandermotten Had skipped a sentence :-)

Comment: @xanatos Indeed! I should sleep more :-) Will fix.

Comment: I was thinking that this was a dead end. I had made this as part of a generic repository and was working fine until I came to these classes as these were the first with derived. I was hoping that I could still use the generic without having to break it apart so thought I'd try and get an answer. This solution worked for me, thanks!

Comment: @ADringer: yeah, these pain-in-the-ass situations are exactly why a loosely coupled contract (aka interface) might make more sense, rather than using the parent class for the `Func<T>` signature. Obviously there's limits to that approach as well. Need to balance the cost-benefits, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite the expressions... Using the [`SimpleParameterReplacer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30918183/613130) I posted in another question:

```
var updatedProperties = Array.ConvertAll(properties, exp =>
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(BankAccount), exp.Parameters[0].Name);
    var body = new SimpleParameterReplacer(exp.Parameters[0], parameter).Visit(exp.Body);
    var exp2 =  Expression.Lambda<Func<BankAccount, object>>(body, parameter);
    return exp2;
});
```

You rewrite the "body" of the expression with `SimpleParameterReplacer()` (to replace the instances of use of the parameter of type `UkBankAccount` with a parameter of type `BankAccount`) and then you rebuild the lambda expression (to change the delegate type).

**Important note**: this code will **only** work if the `SomeProperty` of `x => x.SomeProperty` is part of the **base class** and not of the **derived class**... In your example, `x.Status`, `x.Name`, `x.SortCode`, and `x.AccountNumber` **must** be part of `BankAccount` (or of one of its base classes if present).

Comment: What if one of these properties does not exist on BankAccount?

Comment: @KrisVandermotten Kabooom :-) I read the question as supposing that the fields are present in the base class. If not then the OP should have said what should happen when this precondition isn't satisfied.

Comment: You are on the right track though, but you should also rewrite the body of the expression to include a cast when the property exists only in the derived type. See my answer.