# Cannot convert from `Expression<Func<T1, T2>>` to `Expression<Func<object, object>>`

Tags: c#, generics, expression

**UPDATE**: This question was marked as duplicated, but although I understand the issue with the code, I don't have a solution. Is it possible for the code to work by only changing the method bodies and not the method signatures?

I'm tying to wrap my head around `Expression` and `Func`, while trying to build a class like the following:

```
public class Test<TBase>
{
    private IList<Expression<Func<object, object>>> _expressions = new List<Expression<Func<object, object>>>();

    public void AddExpression<T>(Expression<Func<TBase, T>> e)
    {
        _expressions.Add(e);
    }

    public void AddExpression<T1, T2>(Expression<Func<T1, T2>> e)
    {
        _expressions.Add(e);
    }
}
```

I need/would like to keep a list of expressions, where the types inside the `Func` may vary. I though the code above would work but it doesn't. It fails with:

> `Cannot convert from 'Expression<Func<TBase, T>>' to 'Expression<Func<object, object>>'`
>
> `Cannot convert from 'Expression<Func<T1, T2>>' to 'Expression<Func<object, object>>'`

Resharper says:

> `Argument type 'Expression<Func<TBase, T>>' is not assignable to parameter type 'Expression<Func<object, object>>'`
>
> `Argument type 'Expression<Func<T1, T2>>' is not assignable to parameter type 'Expression<Func<object, object>>'`

Is it possible for the code to work by only changing the method bodies and not the method signatures?

Comment: `Func<T, TResult>` is only covariant on the `TResult` because that's the output, but contravariant on the `T` since that's the input.  So if you have a `Func<int, string>` it's OK for the `string` to be cast to an `object`, but you cannot just pass any `object` in for the `int`.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/42951537/613130, but with the added complexity of requiring cast of the parameter and of the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> UPDATE: This question was marked as duplicated, but although I understand the issue with the code, I don't have a solution. Is it possible for the code to work by only changing the method bodies and not the method signatures?

Yes, you can keep the method signatures, but you'll have to rewrite the expressions...

Like this:

```
public void AddExpression<T1, T2>(Expression<Func<T1, T2>> e)
{
    var originalParameter = e.Parameters[0];

    // object par1
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), originalParameter.Name);

    // T1 var1
    var variable = Expression.Variable(typeof(T1), "var1");

    // (T1)par1
    var cast1 = Expression.Convert(parameter, typeof(T1));

    // var1 = (T1)par1;
    var assign1 = Expression.Assign(variable, cast1);

    // The original body of the expression, with originalParameter replaced with var1
    var body = new SimpleParameterReplacer(originalParameter, variable).Visit(e.Body);

    // (object)body (a cast to object, necessary in the case T2 is a value type. If it is a reference type it isn't necessary)
    var cast2 = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(object));

    // T1 var2; var1 = (T1)par1; (object)body;
    // (the return statement is implicit)
    var block = Expression.Block(new[] { variable }, assign1, cast2);
    var e2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(block, parameter);

    _expressions.Add(e2);
}
```

I'm using the [`SimpleParameterReplacer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30918183/613130) from another response I gave some time ago.

In the end a `(T1 x) => x.Something` (with `x.Something` being a `T2`) is transformed in:

```
(object x) => 
{
    var var1 = (T1)x;
    return (object)var1.Something;
}
```